# Error with creating data driven jquery dropdown menu in asp.net consuming web services

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have gone through the following article and implementing the same i am using webservices instead of wcf services ,`when i run the following html file , the dynamic menu does not display .May i please know where exactly i am going wrong.
This is my html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Sample Test Application</title>
 <style type="text/css">
    .Menu
    {
        width:200px;
        text-align:center;
        border:solid 2px gray;
        padding:0px;
        background-color:Silver;
        cursor:hand;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .MenuItem
    {
        width:192px;
        text-align:center;
        border:solid 1px silver;
        padding:2px;
        background-color:whitesmoke;
    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts\jquery-1.4.1.js">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:50542/MenuItems.asmx/GetMenus",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: CreateMenus,
        error: function(err) {
            alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
        }
    }
    );
});


   function CreateMenus(results) {
 for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  $("<div class='Menu'>" + results[i].Text + "</div>")
     .click({ MenuId: results[i].MenuId }, OnMenuClick)
     .appendTo("#accordionContainer");
 }
}


    function OnMenuClick(event)
     {
    $("div[id ^= 'menuItemGroup']").slideUp(500);
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:50542/MenuItems.asmx/GetMenuItems",
            data: '{"menuId":"' + event.data.MenuId + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(items) {
                $(event.target).children().remove();
                var html = "<div id='menuItemGroup" + event.data.MenuId + "' style='display:none'>";
                for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                    html += "<div class='MenuItem'> <a href='" + items[j].NavigateUrl + "'>"  + 
                    items[j].Text + "</a></div>";
                }
                html += "</div>";
                $(event.target).append(html);
                $("#menuItemGroup" + event.data.MenuId).slideDown(500);
            },
            error: function(err) {
                alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            }
        }
        )
}       


</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="accordionContainer" ></div>
<div class="Menu"></div>
<div class="MenuItem"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my webservice file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace ServiceMahe
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for MenuItems
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class MenuItems : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }



    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public Menu[] GetMenus()
        {
            SampleDataClassesDataContext db = new SampleDataClassesDataContext();
            List<Menu> menus = new List<Menu>();
            var temp = from item in db.Menus
                       select item;
            foreach (var obj in temp)
            {
                Menu m = new Menu();
                m.MenuId = obj.MenuId;
                m.Text = obj.Text;
                menus.Add(m);
            }
            return menus.ToArray();
        }



        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)]
         public MenuItems1[] GetMenuItems(int menuId)
        {
        SampleDataClassesDataContext db = new SampleDataClassesDataContext();
        List<MenuItems1> items = new List<MenuItems1>();
        var temp = from item in db.MenuItems
                   where item.MenuId == menuId
                   select item;
        foreach (var obj in temp)
        {
            MenuItems1 mi = new MenuItems1();
            mi.MenuId = (int)obj.MenuId;
            mi.MenuItemId = obj.MenuItemId;
            mi.Text = obj.Text;
            mi.NavigateUrl = obj.NavigateUrl;
            items.Add(mi);
        }
        return items.ToArray();
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment this line...

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Explanation is in your code itself.

> To allow this Web Service to be
>   called from script, using ASP.NET
>   AJAX, uncomment the following line.

Comment: Even after changing this my menu is empty